# How to compare two line graphs using data points

Tags: sql, excel, math, graph, statistics

I have 2 graphs as below with the blue line indicating an ideal scenario and the orange lines indicating couple of real scenarios. I wanted to check how similar the blue and orange lines are. Looking at the graph, it is obvious that the orange line in chart on top has very similar pattern as blue line. On the other hand, the orange line in bottom chart , has completely conflicting pattern. what is the best way to conclude the orange line in top chart is the better/ closest resembling pattern, mathematically.

[image]

Comment: You could sum the squares of the differences between the points in each pair of "ideal" and "real datasets

Comment: Is it better or equal to calculating difference in slopes at each interval?

Comment: No.  Tim Williams gave you the place to start.  Look at the SSE.

Comment: If it's the shape and not the absolute position you're interested in then maybe something like the variance of the absolute differences between each set of points?